# Передача и приём данных Bluetooth android

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-bluetooth

я новичок в android. 
Я пишу приложения которое должно сначала принять данные при подключении к модулю arduino HC-5, а после по нажатию на кнопку отправить новые данные.
Уже есть кусок отвечающий за сопряжение, в готовых материала даётся код который сразу и подключается и отправляет/принимает данные, но мне этого ненужно.А знаний для выдергивания нужного мне не хватает.
Не мог бы, кто-нибудь поделится, конкретно пошагово методами только для отправки и приёма относительно существующего сокета